# $scope in AngularJS returns nothing in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to return an object, taht I populate in a forEach loop, with angulars $scope from a controller, but when I try to loop it out with ng-repeat I get no result.

When i console.log the object I get the expected result

[image]

But when I try to return it with $scope and show it with ng-repeat I get no results what so ever.

Here is my controller

```
myAppControllers.controller('musicCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

var i = 0,
    playlists = {};

// Get the playlists from soundcloud
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/gimle-sound-tjek/playlists.json?client_id=c2dfe07de1d18d689516884ce22b7aae' }).
    success(function(data) {
        data.forEach(function() {

            // Populate the object
            playlists[i] = {
                "title" : data[i].title,
                "permalink": data[i].permalink,
                "genre": data[i].genre
            }

            i++;
        });

        console.log(playlists);
        $scope.playlists;
    }).
    error(function() {
        $scope.playlists = '';
    });
}]);
```

My ng-repeat looks like this

```
<div ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
<h3>{{ playlist.title }}</h3>
...
```

I am expecting that is has something to do with the way I send the object back with $scope.playlists?

Comment: That together with @Konstantin Krass reply worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all maybe use push instead this `i++` fun.

You push those playlist entries into the playlist variable outside the scope.

```
myAppControllers.controller('musicCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.playlists= [];

// Get the playlists from soundcloud
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://api.soundcloud.com/users/gimle-sound-tjek/playlists.json?client_id=c2dfe07de1d18d689516884ce22b7aae' }).
    success(function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(entry) {    
            // Populate the object
            $scope.playlists.push({
                "title" : entry.title,
                "permalink": entry.permalink,
                "genre": entry.genre
            });
            //OR: $scope.playlists.push(entry);
        });
    }).
    error(function() {
        $scope.playlists = '';
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Init of the variable is missing `$scope.playlists= [];`

Comment: I got it working now, and it all made alot more sense then what i had written. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try `$scope.playlists = []` instead of `var playlist = {}`